# How to change content-type in python while hitting post api?

Tags: python, python-requests

I am working with third-party API where I need to create batch by sending txt file in POST request.

```
params= {'key':'value'}
url = 'htpps://gecoding.com'   //it just a exammple
headers = {'Api-key'='xyz','content-type':'multipart/form-data'}
files = {'file' : open (r'file_path','rb')}
r=request.post(url=url, files=files, params=params, headers=headers, verify=False)
```

After request is made I tried to see headers and it shows application/json
`print(r.headers['content-type']`

Due to this my response affecting. I tried many things but not able to change the content-type
can anyone please help on it to set.

I expect 'content-type' to be 'multipart/form-data' but getting application/json

Comment: Maybe the server only responses with JSON on the URL you are using (whatever URL this really is).

Answer (score 0):

`requests.post()` returns a [`Response`](https://requests.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api/#requests.Response).  'multipart/form-data' is an HTTP ***request*** content type, so I wouldn't expect it in the *response*, and everything seems to be working as expected (provided server is supposed to return JSON upon your request).

You don't need to set request content type either, *requests* set the correct one, given that you pass `files` as a parameter.